# When Rigging a Scorpion-Bot Enemy in Pose Mode the Bones Drift Away from the Mesh when Rotating

Tags: animation, rigging, vertex-groups

at wits end trying to figure out what the issue with my rig is. I am trying to rig a Scorpion Bot I have for a project but once I create the Rig, create all of the Vertex Groups, and parent the mesh to it Using Empty Groups I then try to animate in Pose Mode. But when I do many of the bones will drift away from the mesh when rotated or moved and the Rotation will cap out at 180 degrees and then snap around to another spot. I have watched dozens of Rigging videos and feeling like I haven't missed anything. Also, I note this is a rig I am trying to use in a Unity Project as well. Any help is appreciated, thank you! Below are images showcasing what I am experiencing. Thanks for any advice you may have.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to understand what exactly your problem is, but it seems a simple weighting error.

As robots are supposed not to deform, the condition you have to respect is that every vertex has to be weighted to ONE AND ONLY ONE vertex group.

In your photos it seems that this condition is not present, and vertices are influenced by more than one bone/vertex group.

To solve go to properties window, vertex group tab, choose "delete all vertex groups" from the drop down menu, then re-parent the mesh to the armature using "with empty groups" option, then select all vertices of a body zone, select the relevant vertex group and click the "assign" button (the value of the weight doesn't matter, it can be 1.0 or 0.001, as long as a vertex is asigned to one and only one vertex group, it will follow exactly the respective bone).